# Endless Controllers Cloning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am newbie in iOS programming. I've been looking for this information couple days and I still don't have the best answer, so I ask you for help. Please don't comment it like "Search on google.." or so. I have already did this research.

I have an app with 2 Controllers on start. First is a ViewController and it's a simple TableView. Second one is a controller with navigation bar with two buttons on it - burger on the left and plus on the right. When burger is tapped, first ViewController (with TableView) is opened. This is all very simple, but there's a problem with that plus button - it should add a new controller, which is same as the second controller (same buttons, images, etc.) except 2 labels, that must be different. I don't know if the controller has to be ViewController or NavigationController because I want to have 2 custom buttons on navigation bar (burger, plus). I found something about ContainerView, but I'm not sure, if it's the right way.. I want to switch between controllers using slide gesture.

**Problems**:

1. every next controller has a "plus" button => it can make a new controller.
2. How to make all the controllers looks like the same.

I'm adding an image for better understanding: [IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/p8prs2aal/)

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  Post the code that you have so far so that we can better guide you in the right direction.  Have you tried instantiating another instance of ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your image, a simple solution I will use is using UIScrollView, make paging enabled.

1. Put your tableView and first view controller at the first two pages, and make sure view controllers are all added to the main view controller's childViewController.
2. When plus button tapped, you expand your the scrollView, make the content size bigger, and add a new controller's view to the scrollView, and add the viewController to the mainViewController's childViewController, keep doing that when new view controller needs to be added, and remember to call 'setContentOffset' to scroll to the new page.
3. Because paging is enabled, you can swipe between pages with smooth animation that will stop at each page.

As for your problems, to make the same view controller and add new view controller when tap add button, that are the second step.

**1. Create new view controller:**

1. If you are using storyboard, you need to give the view controller an identifier, and initialize the view controller with:

   UIViewControlller *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your_story_board_name" 
       bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"you_vc_id"];
2. If you are using xib:

   UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_xib_file_name" bundle:nil]
3. If you are using code, just use the

   [UIViewController new]

to create the viewController, they are created with the same source, they surely look the same.

**2. To add the view controller the the next page:**
Let's assume your are currently at the second page, that's the init state of your app, first page is the tableView. 
If the bounds of your scrollView has size of screen size: *size1*, and every page has the same view size: *size1*, and when there are two pages, the content size is *size2*, we know

```
size2.width == size1.width * pages
```

at this point, the

```
size2.width == size1.width * 2
```

So, when a new page need to added, you need to increase the width of content size by size1.width, and set the new viewController.view's frame to

```
(CGRect){(CGPoint){size1.width * page, 0},size1}.
```

Make the add new page a common function, call it when the add button taps.

Hope it helps